# C# Clear a BitmapImage or the instance of it

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I would like to clear a bitmap image.  I've tried both

```
uploadImage.Source = null;
```

and

```
uploadImage.Source = "";
```

This is the code I used to make the image:

```
// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
string curItem = destinationFolder + "\\" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@curItem);
myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
myBitmapImage.EndInit();
uploadImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
```

Comment: What type is `uploadImage`? Maybe it has a `.Clear()` method?

Comment: uploadImage is of type Image. There's no Clear() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uploadImage.Source = null should do it. How are you checking the value of the Source property? I'd suggest [Mole](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MoleForWPF.aspx).
If you are relying on what you see on screen this may be wrong due to property changes not being notified. Try creating a DependencyProperty for the Image or a regular property raising a notification through the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.